# Can BitConverter be used to reliably extract multi-byte values from an IL byte stream (as returned by MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray)?

Tags: clr, endianness, cil, system.reflection, bitconverter

I am working on some code that parses IL byte arrays as returned by [`MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.getilasbytearray.aspx).

Lets say I want to read a metadata token or a 32-bit integer constant from such an IL byte stream. At first I thought using [`BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArray, offset)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx) would make this easy. However I'm now worried that this won't work on big-endian machines.

As far as I know, IL always uses little-endian encoding for multi-byte values:

> *"All argument numbers are encoded least-significant-byte-at-smallest-address (a pattern commonly termed 'little-endian')."* — [The Common Language Infrastructure Annotated Standard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321154932), Partition III, ch. 1.2 (p. 482).

Since `BitConverter`'s conversion methods honour the computer architecture's endianness (which can be discovered through [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx)), I conclude that `BitConverter` should not be used to extract multi-byte values from an IL byte stream, because this would give wrong results on big-endian machines.

Is this conclusion correct?

- If yes: Is there any way to tell `BitConverter` which endianness to use for conversions, or is there any other class in the BCL that offers this functionality, or do I have to write my own conversion code?
- If no: Where am I wrong? What is the proper way of extracting e.g. a `Int32` operand value from an IL byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always do this on a little endian array before passing it:

```
// Array is little. Are we on big?
if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    // Then flip it
    Array.Reverse(array);
}
int val = BitConverter.ToInt32(...);
```

However as you mention an IL stream. The bytecode is this (AFAIK):

```
(OPCODE:(1|2):little) (VARIABLES:x:little)
```

So I would read a byte, check its opcode, then read the appropriate bytes and flip the array if necessary using the above code. Can I ask what you are doing?

Comment: So to extract an `Int32`, and if I don't want to modify the original IL array, I would possibly have to do this on a big-endian machine: `var fragment = new byte[4]; Array.Copy(il, offset, fragment, 0, length: 4); Array.Reverse(fragment); int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(fragment, 0);`. -- Is there any predefined class or method in the BCL that would do the same?

Comment: Not that I know of. Getting this may help you a lot: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm

Comment: Endianness comes into play even for the op-code if you want to compare it against [`OpCode.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcode.value.aspx "MSDN reference page"), which is defined not as `byte[]` but as  `short`.

Comment: @stakx actually, they are one or two byte sequences, not a short